KiwyMD cant scroll fully down on ScrollView displaying an MDList
I am making a music player app and i want to display the songs. I used kivy md because i also want to use it with an android device. To achive the display requirment i set i used the scroll view. Although it properly diplays everything i want i am not fully able to go down.
        directory_path = 'blah.blah.blah'
        self.songs = self.get_all_mp3_files(directory_path)

        song_list = MDList()
        for song_title in self.songs:
            song_item = OneLineListItem(text=song_title)
            song_list.add_widget(song_item)
            self.song_list = song_list
        # Add the song list to the screen
        scroll_view = ScrollView(
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.2},
            do_scroll_y = 0.2,
            scroll_y = 3,
            scroll_distance = 5 ,
            scroll_wheel_distance = 3 ,
            #
        )

        scroll_view.add_widget(song_list)
        self.song_scroll_list = scroll_view

        screen.add_widget(self.song_scroll_list)
        screen.add_widget(self.search_field)
        screen.add_widget(self.search_btn)
        screen.add_widget(self.top_app_bar1)
        screen.add_widget(self.my_songs_label)
        return screen

I have tried adding all these other methods above like do scroll or scroll distance but nothing seems to fix the problem i also tried using the box layout but when i do that i am able to scroll down but the songs go over my other widgets

song_list = MDList(size_hint_y=None) for some reason this doesnt work too

When you use ScrollView, you must set the size_hint of its child to None (or allow the size to grow) for the scroll direction (see the documentation). So try just changing:
song_list = MDList()

to:
song_list = MDList(size_hint_y=None)

